# A Gulp "process terminated with code 1"

Tags: gulp

Hello I am trying to run a task from a gulp file from a tutorial:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    concat = require('gulp-concat'),
    cssmin = require('gulp-cssmin'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

var paths = {
    webroot: "./wwwroot/"
};

paths.bootstrapCss = "./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
paths.sbAdminCss = "./bower_components/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/dist/css/sb-admin-2.css";
paths.fontAwesomeCss = "./bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
paths.morrisCss = "./bower_components/morrisjs/morris.css";

paths.jqueryJs = "./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js";
paths.raphaelJs = "./bower_components/raphael/raphael.js";
paths.morrisJs = "./bower_components/morrisjs/morris.js";

paths.fonts = "./bower_components/font-awesome/fonts/*";

paths.jsDest = paths.webroot + "js";
paths.cssDest = paths.webroot + "css";
paths.fontDest = paths.webroot + "font";

gulp.task("min:js", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.jqueryJs, paths.raphaelJs, paths.morrisJs])
    .pipe(concat(paths.jsDest + "/min/site.min.js"))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));

});

gulp.task("copy.css", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.bootstrapCss, paths.sbAdminCss, paths.fontAwesomeCss])
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssDest));
});
gulp.task("copy:js", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.jqueryJs, paths.raphaelJs, paths.morrisJs])
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.jsDest));
});
gulp.task("copy:css", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.bootstrapCss, paths.sbAdminCss, paths.fontAwesomeCss])
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.cssDest));
});
gulp.task("copy:fonts", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.fonts])
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.fontDest));
});
gulp.task("min:css", function () {
    return gulp.src([paths.bootstrapCss, paths.sbAdminCss, paths.fontAwesomeCss])
    .pipe(concat(paths.cssDest + "/min/site.min.css"))
    .pipe(cssmin())
    .pipe(gulp.dest("."));
});
gulp.task("min", ["min:js", "min:css:"]);
gulp.task("copy", ["copy:js", "copy:css", "copy:fonts"]);
```

the copy task works but min returns "process terminated with code 1". I am not sure what I wrote wrong. Double checked everything but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

The "min" gulp tasks has an invalid dependency

"min:css:" should be "min:css". Note the trailing ":"